# Implementing Swipe action on ViewFlipper with multiple GridViews

Tags: android

I have the following code to listen to Swipe action to navigate between GridViews in my ViewFlipper. However, it detects the Swipe inconsistently. I added the Gesture Listener to every GridView and also on every item in the GridView. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Full code is below:

```
public class ListNewsActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {

String TAG = "ListNewsActivity";

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

private static final int DIALOG_PLEASE_WAIT = 100;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

private Animation slideLeftIn;
private Animation slideLeftOut;
private Animation slideRightIn;
private Animation slideRightOut;

private static int MAX_STREAMS = AppSettings.getStreamList().size();

Context context;

ViewFlipper flipper;

StreamHeader header;

int currentStreamIndex = 0;

ArrayList<StreamNav> navList = new ArrayList<StreamNav>();
ArrayList<StreamGridView> gridList = new ArrayList<StreamGridView>();


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    context = getApplicationContext();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stream);

    if (AppSettings.userToken == null) {
        AppSettings.getUserToken(context);
    }

    header = (StreamHeader) findViewById(R.id.stream_header);
    setHeaderTitle();

    flipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.stream_flipper);

    boolean loadData = false;
    Log.v(TAG, "No. of streams: " + String.valueOf(AppSettings.getStreamList().size()));
    for (Stream stream : AppSettings.getStreamList()) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Checking Stream  " + stream.getName());
        if (stream.getPosts() == null || stream.getPosts().size() == 0) {
            loadData = true;
            Log.v(TAG, "Empty Stream for " + stream.getBlogId() + ". Data will be loaded.");
            break;
        }
        else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Stream " + stream.getName() + " is populated. Posts: " + String.valueOf(stream.getPosts().size()));
        }
    }

    setupNavAndGrids();

    if (loadData) {
        new LoadStreamTask().execute();
    }
    else {
        populateGrids();
    }

    slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.stream_flipper_slidein_from_right);
    slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.stream_flipper_slideout_to_left);
    slideRightIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.stream_flipper_slidein_from_left);
    slideRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.stream_flipper_slideout_to_right);

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

}

public void setupNavAndGrids() {

    LinearLayout llNav = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.stream_nav_layout);

    View.OnClickListener navOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            StreamNav nav = (StreamNav)v;
            navigateToStream(nav.getStreamIndex());

        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STREAMS; i++) {
        StreamNav nav = new StreamNav(context, null);
        nav.setStreamIndex(i);
        nav.setOnClickListener(navOnClickListener);
        navList.add(nav);
        llNav.addView(nav);

        StreamGridView gv = new StreamGridView(context, null);
        gv.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
        gridList.add(gv);

        flipper.addView(gv);

    }

    navList.get(0).setSelected(true);

}

void navigateToStream(int newStreamIndex) {

    for (StreamNav nav : navList) {
        if (nav.getStreamIndex() == newStreamIndex) {
            nav.setSelected(true);
        }
        else {
            nav.setSelected(false);
        }
    }
    Log.v(TAG, "Navigate To Stream: currentStreamIndex=" + String.valueOf(currentStreamIndex) + " newStreamIndex " + String.valueOf(newStreamIndex));
    if (currentStreamIndex < newStreamIndex) {
        int ctr = newStreamIndex - currentStreamIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < ctr; i++) {
            showNext();
        }
    }
    else {
        int ctr =  currentStreamIndex - newStreamIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < ctr; i++) {
            showPrevious();
        }
    }
}

public void showNext() {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Show Next Page for Flipper", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    flipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.stream_flipper_slidein_from_right);
    flipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.stream_flipper_slideout_to_left);
    flipper.showNext();
    setStreamIndex(1);
    setHeaderTitle();
    }

public void showPrevious() {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Show Previous Page for Flipper", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    flipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.stream_flipper_slidein_from_left);
    flipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.stream_flipper_slideout_to_right);
    flipper.showPrevious();
    setStreamIndex(-1);
    setHeaderTitle();
}

void setStreamIndex(int step) {
    if (step == 1) {
        if (currentStreamIndex == MAX_STREAMS) {
            currentStreamIndex = 0;
        }
        else {
            currentStreamIndex++;
        }
    }
    else {
        // -1 which means previous
        if (currentStreamIndex == 0) {
            currentStreamIndex = MAX_STREAMS - 1;
        }
        else {
            currentStreamIndex--;
        }
    }
}

void setHeaderTitle() {
    header.setTitle(AppSettings.getStreamList().get(currentStreamIndex).getName());
}

void populateGrids() {
    int pos = -1;
    for (StreamGridView sgv : gridList) {
        pos++;
        Log.v(TAG, "Loading Stream for " + AppSettings.getStreamList().get(pos).getName() + "; Posts: " + String.valueOf(AppSettings.getStreamList().get(pos).getPosts().size()));
        ArrayList<Post> posts = AppSettings.getStreamList().get(pos).getPosts();
        sgv.adapter = new LazyPostItemAdapter(ListNewsActivity.this, posts, gestureListener);
        sgv.gvStream.setAdapter(sgv.adapter);

    }
}
class LoadStreamTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_PLEASE_WAIT);

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

        for (Stream stream : AppSettings.getStreamList()) {

            if (stream.getBlogId().equalsIgnoreCase("popular")) {
                stream.setPosts(Post.getPopularStream());
            }
            else if (stream.getBlogId().equalsIgnoreCase("recent")) {
                stream.setPosts(Post.getRecentStream());
            }
            else {
                Blog blog = Blog.getBlog(stream.getBlogId());
                stream.setPosts(Post.getPostsForBlog(blog));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

        populateGrids();
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_PLEASE_WAIT);
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_PLEASE_WAIT:
            ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading Streams...");
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onFling");
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                flipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                flipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                flipper.showNext();
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                flipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                flipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                flipper.showPrevious();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I keep seeing the same swipe gesture detection code all over StackOverflow, so I have attempted to clean it up a bit. This is a generic listener which can fire events for right or left swipes (easily extended to other

```
public class SwipeListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    private SwipeHandler handler;

    public SwipeHandler getHandler() {
        return handler;
    }

    public void setHandler(SwipeHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
            return false;

        // left
        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

            if (handler != null) {
                handler.onLeft();

                return true;
            }

        // right
        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

            if (handler != null) {
                handler.onRight();

                return true;
            }
        }

        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }

    public static abstract class SwipeHandler{
        public void onLeft() {}
        public void onRight() {}
    }
}
```

And then to use this anywhere, just create an instance, setup your swipe event handlers, and attach it:

```
    SwipeListener swipeListener = new SwipeListener();
    swipeListener.setHandler(new SwipeListener.SwipeHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onRight() {
            doSomething();
        }
    });

    someView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Comment: looks like this is the original source of the snippet that everyone is copying: http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2010/04/swipe-action-and-viewflipper-in-android.html

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of questions/observations here:

Q: Can you elaborate on what you mean by inconsistently? Is there any pattern to when the swipe is not    detected? Does it work at all? If so, when?

Q: In your main Activity, in the over-riden onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) method do you return    myGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(me) like this?

```
@Override    
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
     return myGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(me);    
}
```

here myGestureDetector is an object of your MyGestureDetector class and this basically attaches your GestureDetector to the touch event

Observation: Can you please return true as soon as your gesture processing is done, that tells android that the gesture capture is done, for example

```
        if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            flipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
            flipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
            flipper.showNext();
            //return true if the gesture event is consumed
            return true; 
        }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            flipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
            flipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
            flipper.showPrevious();
            //return true if the gesture event is consumed
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Sometimes the swipe works, sometimes it does. It works more when swiping to the right. I updated the question with the full code.

Answer (score 0):

1) have u added all the gridviews in viewflipper.

```
viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);
            slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_in);
            slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_out);
            slideRightIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_in);
            slideRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_out);

            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
            gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() 
                {
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                    {
                        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) 
                        {
                                return true;
                        }
                        else{
                                return false;}
                        }
                };
```

I have added these in my code it is working fine.just check this let me know

Comment: Yes I have those. I have the same exact code for a ViewFlipper with TextViews. However, if I have GridViews, it doesn't work. Does your app have GridViews in your ViewFlipper?