# Help with android layout

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout, android-widget

I want to create a UI similar to the images shown in the links given below.

http://www.4shared.com/photo/EU1KsEPC/device1.html

http://www.4shared.com/photo/tcQMx75T/device2.html

The requirement is, when I swipe to the right, it should go to the 2nd, 3rd pages and so on. And swiping to the left should go to the previous page.

How can I create such a UI? What layout should I use?

Any help in this regard would be well appreciated with points.

Best Regards,
Rony

Comment: Image links are broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look into a GridView.

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

Perhaps your looking for this answer?

[Implementing Swipe action on ViewFlipper with multiple GridViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162720/implementing-swipe-action-on-viewflipper-with-multiple-gridviews)

Comment: I have tried that prior to posting my query here. The problem with gridview is that, it makes the page grow vertically and does not support horizontal. I need to have a page like structure as shown in the images given in the links and with gridview, I would not be able to achieve that.

Comment: I am not sure whether I ought to use multiple gridiews. I load my gridviews in a stretch. I use the same example as shown here(http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) to create my gridview.  I presume, I am not sure whether it is an efficient solution to create multiple views with a smalll set of data. If at all, that is a requisite, I do not knpw how to create multiple gridviews from the example shown.

Comment: I thinks you dont need to be afraid performance wise. The whole intents / view system will handle that. Personally i don't think its possible to do this with just 1 view + users wont know/feel the difference. I hope i helped abit :) Good luck with your application